# Maintaining Parent Nodes during AVL Rotation in C

Tags: c, rotation, avl-tree

I am implementing an AVL Tree in C and also need to create an iterator. As such, I need to maintain parent nodes to iterate through the tree in constant time. I am having trouble maintaining the parents during the tree balancing. Here is what I have:

```
/*Balance factor of -2 with Right Child -1*/
static AVLPtr RRRotation(AVLPtr root){
    AVLPtr rightChild = root->rightChild;
    root->rightChild = rightChild->leftChild;

    if(rightChild->leftChild != NULL){
        rightChild->leftChild->parent = root;
   }

   rightChild->leftChild = root;

   if(rightChild != NULL){
       rightChild->parent = root->parent;
   }

   if(root != NULL){
       root->parent = rightChild;
   }

   return rightChild;
}

/*Balance factor of +2 with Left Child +1*/
static AVLPtr LLRotation(AVLPtr root){
  AVLPtr leftChild = root->leftChild;

   root->leftChild = leftChild->rightChild;

   if(leftChild->rightChild != NULL){
       leftChild->rightChild->parent = root;
   }

   leftChild->rightChild = root;

   if(leftChild != NULL){
       leftChild->parent = root->parent;
   }

   if(root != NULL){
       root->parent = leftChild;
   }

   return leftChild;
}

/*Balance factor of -2 with Right Child +1*/
static AVLPtr RLRotation(AVLPtr root){
   AVLPtr rightChild = root->rightChild;

   AVLPtr temp = LLRotation(rightChild);

   if(temp != NULL){
       temp->parent = root;
   }

   root->rightChild = temp;

   AVLPtr temp2 = RRRotation(root);

   if(temp2 != NULL){
       temp2->parent = root->parent;
   }

   return temp2;
}

/*Balance factor of +2 with Left Child -1*/
static AVLPtr LRRotation(AVLPtr root){
   AVLPtr leftChild = root->leftChild;

   AVLPtr temp = RRRotation(leftChild);

   if(temp != NULL){
       temp->parent = root;
   }

   root->leftChild =temp;

   AVLPtr temp2 = LLRotation(root);

   if(temp2 != NULL){
       temp2->parent = root->parent;
   }

   return temp2;
}
```

I think I am doing something wrong in my RL and LR rotations but just can't seem to figure out what. Also, some of the if statements are probably unneeded but that *shouldn't* matter.

Answer (score 0):

I checked `RRRotation` and didn't see any errors, but found it very difficult to follow. A quick check of `LLRotation` also didn't turn up any errors. I didn't check the other two because by that time my head was spinning.

Seems to me that you could simplify the logic with a couple more local variables, which would then make it easier to verify the logic. Here's how I would write the `RRRotation` function.

```
static AVLPtr RRRotation(AVLPtr root)
{
    AVLPtr parent = root->parent;       // the parent of the root node
    AVLPtr child  = root->rightChild;   // the child of the root node
    AVLPtr baby   = child->leftChild;   // the child of the child node

    child->parent = parent;
    child->leftChild = root;

    root->parent = child;
    root->rightChild = baby;

    if ( baby )
        baby->parent = root;
}
```